# Modifying an SQL query for All Combinations of Two Variables

Tags: group-by

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table ("my_table"):

```
  id year var1 var3 date_1
1  1 2017    1    1    NA
2  1 2018    0    1    NA
3  1 2019    1    1    NA
4  2 2017    0    1    NA
5  2 2018    1    1    NA
6  3 2017    1    1    NA
7  3 2018    1    1    NA
8  3 2019    0    1    NA
```

I have the following query:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        year,
        SUM(var1) AS var1mod,
        date_1
    FROM my_table
    WHERE var3 = 1
    GROUP BY id, year, date1
),

cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        id
    FROM cte1
    WHERE var1mod = 0
),

cte3 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS year_count
    FROM cte1
    WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte2)
    AND date_1 IS NULL
    GROUP BY id
),

cte4 AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        MIN(year) AS min_year
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT
    year_count,
    COUNT(*) AS count_per_year
FROM cte3
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte4 WHERE min_year = 2000)
GROUP BY year_count;
```

**My Question:**

- In the above query, I am running this for min_year = 2000 and var1mod = 0
- **Is it possible to run this query for all possible combinations of min_year and var1mod?**

Currently, I have manually copy/pasted this query multiple times and used a series of UNION ALL statements to accomplish this task - but can someone please show me how I can aggregate this query to run it for all possible combinations of min_year and var1mod?

Thanks!

Comment: Just remove your `WHERE` clauses on those 2 fields, and it'll run for everything?

Comment: @J.D. thank you for your reply! I want to add these two variables in the final group by statement ... is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can add them to the existing `GROUP BY` clause you have.